I have issue in using Gnosis wallet
https://help.safe.global/en/articles/40825-supported-asset-types
It says we can store any ERC20 tokens in the safe wallet, but I can not see my asset in the safe account dashboard.

Is there any 'add asset' function in the gnosis dashboard?

This seems to be a problem linked to Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page and explain the problem to them.
This stack exchange tag (safe-core) is more intended to be used for developers having trouble building on top of Safe{Core}.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis

Thanks, it was the issue from the Safe Wallet.
I contacted the support team and resolved issue.
Also there is a way to build the transaction using transaction object mode in the Gnosis wallet.
